Plotly how to change the range and color of gauge programatically
I want to update the range of the colored steps range of a gauge dynamically.
The gauge:


var humidityData = [
  {
    domain: { x: [0, 1], y: [0, 1] },
    value: 0,
    title: { text: "Feuchtigkeit" },
    type: "indicator",
    mode: "gauge+number+delta",
    delta: { reference: 69 },
    gauge: {
      axis: { range: [40, 103] },
      steps: [
        { range: [10, 65], color: "red" },
        { range: [65, 68], color: "yellow" },
        { range: [68, 75], color: "lightgreen" },
        { range: [75, 78], color: "yellow" },
        { range: [78, 103], color: "red" },
      ],
    },
  },
];



But the following does not update the ranges:


if (temperature_soll!=20) {
    var temp_soll = ((20*1.8)+32)
    var temperature_update = {
      value: temperature,
      'delta.reference': temp_soll,
      'gauge.axis.range': [((10*1.8)+32), ((30*1.8)+32)],
      'gauge.steps.range': [((10*1.8)+32), ((15*1.8)+32)], color:"red",
      'gauge.steps.range': [((15*1.8)+32), ((18*1.8)+32)], color: "yellow",
      'gauge.steps.range': [((18*1.8)+32), ((22*1.8)+32)], color: "lightgreen",
      'gauge.steps.range': [((22*1.8)+32), ((25*1.8)+32)], color: "yellow",
      'gauge.steps.range': [((25*1.8)+32), ((30*1.8)+32)], color: "red",
    };
  };



The colored ranges are still the same:

On a previous post of me, it was the speciality of nested values.
Seems to be here something the same, but in a different way.
Any hint on that would be nice.
Kind regards
Frank
For better understanding, here the full main.js:


var temperatureHistoryDiv = document.getElementById("temperature-history");
var humidityHistoryDiv = document.getElementById("humidity-history");

var temperatureGaugeDiv = document.getElementById("temperature-gauge");
var humidityGaugeDiv = document.getElementById("humidity-gauge");

// History Data
var temperatureTrace = {
  x: [],
  y: [],
  name: "Temperatur",
  mode: "lines+markers",
  type: "line",
};
var humidityTrace = {
  x: [],
  y: [],
  name: "Feuchtigkeit",
  mode: "lines+markers",
  type: "line",
};

var temperatureLayout = {
  autosize: false,
  title: {
    text: "Temperatur",
  },
  font: {
    size: 14,
    color: "#7f7f7f",
  },
  colorway: ["#B22222"],
  width: 450,
  height: 260,
  margin: { t: 30, b: 20, pad: 5 },
};
var humidityLayout = {
  autosize: false,
  title: {
    text: "Feuchtigkeit",
  },
  font: {
    size: 14,
    color: "#7f7f7f",
  },
  colorway: ["#00008B"],
  width: 450,
  height: 260,
  margin: { t: 30, b: 20, pad: 5 },
};

Plotly.newPlot(temperatureHistoryDiv, [temperatureTrace], temperatureLayout);
Plotly.newPlot(humidityHistoryDiv, [humidityTrace], humidityLayout);

// Gauge Data
var temperatureData = [
  {
    domain: { x: [0, 1], y: [0, 1] },
    value: 0,
    title: { text: "Temperatur" },
    type: "indicator",
    mode: "gauge+number+delta",
    delta: { reference: 20 },
    gauge: {
      axis: { range: [10, 30] },
      steps: [
        { range: [10, 15], color: "red" },
        { range: [15, 18], color: "yellow" },
        { range: [18, 22], color: "lightgreen" },
        { range: [22, 25], color: "yellow" },
        { range: [25, 30], color: "red" },
      ],
    },
  },
];

var humidityData = [
  {
    domain: { x: [0, 1], y: [0, 1] },
    value: 0,
    title: { text: "Feuchtigkeit" },
    type: "indicator",
    mode: "gauge+number+delta",
    delta: { reference: 69 },
    gauge: {
      axis: { range: [40, 103] },
      steps: [
        { range: [10, 65], color: "red" },
        { range: [65, 68], color: "yellow" },
        { range: [68, 75], color: "lightgreen" },
        { range: [75, 78], color: "yellow" },
        { range: [78, 103], color: "red" },
      ],
    },
  },
];

var layout = { width: 300, height: 250, margin: { t: 0, b: 0, l: 0, r: 0 }};

Plotly.newPlot(temperatureGaugeDiv, temperatureData, layout);
Plotly.newPlot(humidityGaugeDiv, humidityData, layout);

// Will hold the arrays we receive from our BME280 sensor
// Temperature
let newTempXArray = [];
let newTempYArray = [];
// Humidity
let newHumidityXArray = [];
let newHumidityYArray = [];

// The maximum number of data points displayed on our scatter/line graph
let MAX_GRAPH_POINTS = 60;
let ctr = 0;

// Callback function that will retrieve our latest sensor readings and redraw our Gauge with the latest readings
function updateSensorReadings() {
  fetch(`/sensorReadings`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((jsonResponse) => {
      let temperature_soll = jsonResponse.temperature_soll.toFixed(1);
      let temperature = jsonResponse.temperature.toFixed(1);
      let humidity = jsonResponse.humidity.toFixed(1);
      let humidity_soll = jsonResponse.humidity_soll.toFixed(1);
      

      updateBoxes(temperature, humidity);

      updateGauge(temperature_soll, temperature, humidity, humidity_soll);

      // Update Temperature Line Chart
      updateCharts(
        temperatureHistoryDiv,
        newTempXArray,
        newTempYArray,
        temperature
      );
      // Update Humidity Line Chart
      updateCharts(
        humidityHistoryDiv,
        newHumidityXArray,
        newHumidityYArray,
        humidity
      );
    });
}

function updateBoxes(temperature, humidity, pressure, altitude) {
  let temperatureDiv = document.getElementById("temperature");
  let humidityDiv = document.getElementById("humidity");

  temperatureDiv.innerHTML = temperature + " C";
  humidityDiv.innerHTML = humidity + " %";
}

function updateGauge(temperature_soll, temperature, humidity, humidity_soll) {
  //Celsius values in json
  if (temperature_soll==20) {
    var temperature_update = {
      value: temperature,
      'delta.reference': temperature_soll,
      'gauge.axis': [
        { range: [10, 30] },
      ],
      'gauge.steps': [
        { range: [10, 15], color: "red" },
        { range: [15, 18], color: "yellow" },
        { range: [18, 22], color: "lightgreen" },
        { range: [22, 25], color: "yellow" },
        { range: [25, 30], color: "red" },
      ],
    };
  };
  //Fahrenheit values in json
  if (temperature_soll!=20) {
    //var temp_soll = ((20*1.8)+32)
    var temperature_update = {
      value: temperature,
      'delta.reference': 68,
      'gauge.axis': [
        { range: [50, 86] },
      ],
      'gauge.steps': [
        { range: [50, 59], color: "red" },
        { range: [((15*1.8)+32), ((18*1.8)+32)], color: "yellow" },
        { range: [((18*1.8)+32), ((22*1.8)+32)], color: "lightgreen" },
        { range: [((22*1.8)+32), ((25*1.8)+32)], color: "yellow" },
        { range: [((25*1.8)+32), ((30*1.8)+32)], color: "red" },
      ],
    };
  };
  
  
  var humidity_update = {
    value: humidity,
    'delta.reference': humidity_soll,
  };
  Plotly.update(temperatureGaugeDiv, temperature_update);
  Plotly.update(humidityGaugeDiv, humidity_update);
}

function updateCharts(lineChartDiv, xArray, yArray, sensorRead) {
  if (xArray.length >= MAX_GRAPH_POINTS) {
    xArray.shift();
  }
  if (yArray.length >= MAX_GRAPH_POINTS) {
    yArray.shift();
  }
  xArray.push(ctr++);
  yArray.push(sensorRead);

  var data_update = {
    x: [xArray],
    y: [yArray],
  };

  Plotly.update(lineChartDiv, data_update);
}


// Continuos loop that runs evry 3 seconds to update our web page with the latest sensor readings
(function loop() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    updateSensorReadings();
    loop();
  }, 3000);
})();




It seems you need to rebuild the entire gauge object, actually in your situation the simplest is to rebuild the trace since you got all the info for updating. Here is the full code (it switches randomly between the two json mocks you've provided in the comments) :


var temperatureHistoryDiv = document.getElementById("temperature-history");
var humidityHistoryDiv = document.getElementById("humidity-history");

var temperatureGaugeDiv = document.getElementById("temperature-gauge");
var humidityGaugeDiv = document.getElementById("humidity-gauge");

// History Data
var temperatureTrace = {
  x: [],
  y: [],
  name: "Temperatur",
  mode: "lines+markers",
  type: "line",
};
var humidityTrace = {
  x: [],
  y: [],
  name: "Feuchtigkeit",
  mode: "lines+markers",
  type: "line",
};

var temperatureLayout = {
  autosize: false,
  title: {
    text: "Temperatur",
  },
  font: {
    size: 14,
    color: "#7f7f7f",
  },
  colorway: ["#B22222"],
  width: 450,
  height: 260,
  margin: { t: 30, b: 20, pad: 5 },
};
var humidityLayout = {
  autosize: false,
  title: {
    text: "Feuchtigkeit",
  },
  font: {
    size: 14,
    color: "#7f7f7f",
  },
  colorway: ["#00008B"],
  width: 450,
  height: 260,
  margin: { t: 30, b: 20, pad: 5 },
};

Plotly.newPlot(temperatureHistoryDiv, [temperatureTrace], temperatureLayout);
Plotly.newPlot(humidityHistoryDiv, [humidityTrace], humidityLayout);

// Gauge Data
var temperatureData = [
  {
    domain: { x: [0, 1], y: [0, 1] },
    value: 0,
    title: { text: "Temperatur" },
    type: "indicator",
    mode: "gauge+number+delta",
    delta: { reference: 20 },
    gauge: {
      axis: { range: [10, 30] },
      steps: [
        { range: [10, 15], color: "red" },
        { range: [15, 18], color: "yellow" },
        { range: [18, 22], color: "lightgreen" },
        { range: [22, 25], color: "yellow" },
        { range: [25, 30], color: "red" },
      ],
    },
  },
];

var humidityData = [
  {
    domain: { x: [0, 1], y: [0, 1] },
    value: 0,
    title: { text: "Feuchtigkeit" },
    type: "indicator",
    mode: "gauge+number+delta",
    delta: { reference: 69 },
    gauge: {
      axis: { range: [40, 103] },
      steps: [
        { range: [10, 65], color: "red" },
        { range: [65, 68], color: "yellow" },
        { range: [68, 75], color: "lightgreen" },
        { range: [75, 78], color: "yellow" },
        { range: [78, 103], color: "red" },
      ],
    },
  },
];

var layout = { width: 300, height: 250, margin: { t: 0, b: 0, l: 0, r: 0 }};

Plotly.newPlot(temperatureGaugeDiv, temperatureData, layout);
Plotly.newPlot(humidityGaugeDiv, humidityData, layout);

// Will hold the arrays we receive from our BME280 sensor
// Temperature
let newTempXArray = [];
let newTempYArray = [];
// Humidity
let newHumidityXArray = [];
let newHumidityYArray = [];

// The maximum number of data points displayed on our scatter/line graph
let MAX_GRAPH_POINTS = 60;
let ctr = 0;

// Callback function that will retrieve our latest sensor readings and redraw our Gauge with the latest readings
function updateSensorReadings() {
  // fetch(`/sensorReadings`)
  //   .then((response) => response.json())
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const json = Math.random() <= 0.5 ? {
      "status":"ok",
      "temperature_soll":68,
      "temperature":76.4240036,
      "humidity":42.64257813,
      "humidity_soll":30
    } : {"status":"ok",
      "temperature_soll":20,
      "temperature":24.71999931,
      "humidity":42.51953125,
      "humidity_soll":30
    };
    
    resolve(json); 
  }).then((jsonResponse) => {
      let temperature_soll = jsonResponse.temperature_soll.toFixed(1);
      let temperature = jsonResponse.temperature.toFixed(1);
      let humidity = jsonResponse.humidity.toFixed(1);
      let humidity_soll = jsonResponse.humidity_soll.toFixed(1);
      

      updateBoxes(temperature, humidity);

      updateGauge(temperature_soll, temperature, humidity, humidity_soll);

      // Update Temperature Line Chart
      updateCharts(
        temperatureHistoryDiv,
        newTempXArray,
        newTempYArray,
        temperature
      );
      // Update Humidity Line Chart
      updateCharts(
        humidityHistoryDiv,
        newHumidityXArray,
        newHumidityYArray,
        humidity
      );
    });
}

function updateBoxes(temperature, humidity, pressure, altitude) {
  let temperatureDiv = document.getElementById("temperature");
  let humidityDiv = document.getElementById("humidity");

  temperatureDiv.innerHTML = temperature + " C";
  humidityDiv.innerHTML = humidity + " %";
}

function updateGauge(temperature_soll, temperature, humidity, humidity_soll) {
  //Celsius values in json
  if (temperature_soll==20) {
    var temperature_update = {
      value: temperature,
      delta: { reference: temperature_soll },
      gauge: {
        axis: { range: [10, 30] },
        steps: [
        { range: [10, 15], color: "red" },
        { range: [15, 18], color: "yellow" },
        { range: [18, 22], color: "lightgreen" },
        { range: [22, 25], color: "yellow" },
        { range: [25, 30], color: "red" },
        ],
      },
    };
  };
  //Fahrenheit values in json
  if (temperature_soll!=20) {
    var temperature_update = {
      value: temperature,
      delta: { reference: 68 },
      gauge: {
        axis: { range: [50, 86] },
        steps: [
          { range: [50, 59], color: "red" },
          { range: [((15*1.8)+32), ((18*1.8)+32)], color: "yellow" },
          { range: [((18*1.8)+32), ((22*1.8)+32)], color: "lightgreen" },
          { range: [((22*1.8)+32), ((25*1.8)+32)], color: "yellow" },
          { range: [((25*1.8)+32), ((30*1.8)+32)], color: "red" },
        ]
      }   
    };
  };
  
  var humidity_update = {
    value: humidity,
    'delta.reference': humidity_soll,
  };
  Plotly.restyle(temperatureGaugeDiv, temperature_update);
  Plotly.update(humidityGaugeDiv, humidity_update);
}

function updateCharts(lineChartDiv, xArray, yArray, sensorRead) {
  if (xArray.length >= MAX_GRAPH_POINTS) {
    xArray.shift();
  }
  if (yArray.length >= MAX_GRAPH_POINTS) {
    yArray.shift();
  }
  xArray.push(ctr++);
  yArray.push(sensorRead);

  var data_update = {
    x: [xArray],
    y: [yArray],
  };

  Plotly.update(lineChartDiv, data_update);
}


// Continuos loop that runs evry 3 seconds to update our web page with the latest sensor readings
(function loop() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    updateSensorReadings();
    loop();
  }, 3000);
})();
<head>
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.32.0.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='myDiv'></div>
    <div id='temperature'></div>
    <div id='humidity'></div>    
    <div id='temperature-history'></div>
    <div id='humidity-history'></div>  
    <div id='temperature-gauge'></div>
    <div id='humidity-gauge'></div>
</body>




Hey Eric,
it compiles without errors, bute the colored ranges are sadly not applied.
No color is visible so far.
Kind regards
Frank

I think that's because you are mislead by the answer in your previous post : you should apply the update with Plotly.update(temperatureGaugeDiv, temperature_update); not Plotly.update(temperatureGaugeDiv, [temperature_update]);. If there is still an issue, please edit your post and add the full code or at least a mwe with the initial temperature data (not the humidityData because I guess it belongs to humidityGaugeDiv) + the plot update).

Hello Eric,
I already mentioned the braces and corrected them. Otherwise they wont update at all, even without the changing of the range colors.
For better understanding, I add the full main.js obove.
Hopefully it could be better to understand then...

Here an example of the json String (fahrenheit):
{"status":"ok","temperature_soll":68,"temperature":76.4240036,"humidity":42.64257813,"humidity_soll":30}
And one for Celsius:
{"status":"ok","temperature_soll":20,"temperature":24.71999931,"humidity":42.51953125,"humidity_soll":30}
Just to complete all infos.

Ah ok, it seems there is an issue with the overriding syntax for the nested gauge properties. Rebuilding the trace works fine though, see revised answer with a fully runable code snippet.

Thats it Eric :-)
Thank you so much in this!
You really made my day.
Frank
